# C: How can I check if a memory address has been written?

Tags: c, stack, memory-address, buffer-overflow

Is there a way in C to check if a memory address of my own process is written?
For example: if my program accepts an input that is placed in a buffer, can I check if the input has overflowed the buffer by checking if the next address to the buffer has been written?
I know that I can check the content of the next address to the buffer and verify if it has been modified, but this way it's not good for what I'm working on...

I'm doing a study on a protection in case both buffer overflow and format string bugs are present

Comment: Strictly speaking once buffer overflow (or any UB) has occurred all bets are off. The only way to deal with buffer overflow is to ensure it doesn't happen.

Comment: I know, but my question was a different one...

Comment: You can fill a buffer with some value (0x00, 0xff ?) and then "use" a subset of that buffer - then check if your preset values have been overwritten beyond where you think they should have been.

Comment: yes I thought about it, but if there is a string bug format vulnerability, I could read the contents of the stack and enter the exact values (0x00, 0xff). As a result, this type of control would not work.

Comment: @Mark you need to elaborate your last comment about the "string bug format vulnerability". Maybe even [edit] your question and include that _there_. You also should tell us "what you're  working on".

Comment: Anyway basically the only way to deal with buffer overflow is what is suggested in the first and fourth comments.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok, sorry. I modified the post.

Comment: Refering to 4th comment: Instead of filling the part of the buffer which is not supposed to be overwritten with a fixed value you could fill it with an sequence of random bytes.

Comment: At least in the case of allocated memory valgrind can detect accesses outwith allocated blocks. You may be able either to use this, or from looking at its source get some hints. https://valgrind.org/

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, after all the stack canary is exactly that sequence of random bytes. But being able to read the stack via format string bug, then I'll be able to insert exactly those random bytes

Comment: @Markthen I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: @Jabberwocky hahah why? I'm just working on this kind of scenario. And trying to make a protection.

Comment: @Mark I'm out of ideas here. Maybe someone else has another idea.

Comment: Seems to me you're asking the wrong question here. You shouldn't be asking how to detect when data has overflowed a buffer. You should be asking how to *prevent* data from overflowing a buffer. In particular, if your program accepts input, it's up to your program to prevent that input from overflowing whatever buffer you have allocated for it.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can check the content of the next address to the buffer and verify if it has been modified, but this way it's not good for what I'm working on...

Unfortunately that is the *only* possibility you have when using C without platform and implementation-specific extensions.

However, there are C compilers that can produce machine code which will detect *many* buffer overflows in these kinds of context - for example GCC has switches `-fsanitize=undefined` and `-fsanitize=address` which can be used together and which will output diagnostics to the terminal when a buffer overflow happens. They make the program much slower to run. Alternatively you can use `valgrind` to run the program, and it too can debug many kinds cases where an allocated buffer is overrun.

Answer (score 0):

To add to your study:

If programming on linux platform that supports `mprotect` call and when dealing with only dynamic allocation, you can overallocate the memory to at least more then 1 page and `mprotect` the memory after the memory that you return as dynamically allocated.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <signal.h>

#if PROTECT_ME
void *malloc2(size_t size) {
    const size_t maxalign = _Alignof(max_align_t);
    assert(size < getpagesize() - sizeof(size_t) - maxalign); // roughly, could be TODO

    // allocate memory
    char * const pnt = mmap(NULL, getpagesize() + 1,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    assert(pnt != (void*)-1);
    assert((uintptr_t)pnt % getpagesize() == 0);

    // calculate a pointer right after the returned pointer that has
    // to be aligned
    char * const end = pnt + getpagesize();
    char * const beg = end - size - (size % maxalign);

    // I store size in the memory before the data
    memcpy(beg - sizeof(size), &size, sizeof(size));

    // protect the data behind the pointer
    assert((uintptr_t)end % getpagesize() == 0);
    const int err = mprotect(end, 1, 0);
    assert(err == 0);

    return beg;
}

void free2(void *beg) {
    // extract size for memory preceding the data
    size_t size;
    memcpy(&size, beg - sizeof(size), sizeof(size));

    // calculate mmap returned pointer
    const size_t maxalign = _Alignof(max_align_t);
    char * const end = beg + size + (size % maxalign);
    char * const pnt = end - getpagesize();

    assert((uintptr_t)pnt % getpagesize() == 0);
    int err = munmap(pnt, getpagesize() * 2);
    assert(err == 0);
}

void signal_segv(int a) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The process had written to a bad place\n");
    abort();
}

__attribute__((__constructor__))
void _init_me(void) {
    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_segv);
}

#define malloc malloc2
#define free free2

#endif


int main() {
    int *a = malloc(5 * sizeof(*a));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;  // will write out-of-bounds for a array when i == 5
        fprintf(stderr, "a[%d]=%d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}
```

Compiling with `gcc` and running without protection:

```
$ gcc 1.c && ./a.out
a[0]=0
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=3
a[4]=4
a[5]=5
a[6]=6
a[7]=7
a[8]=8
a[9]=9
```

But with protection enabled on a platform the SIGSEGV should generated when writing "enough" (alignment) out-of-bounds to the array:

```
$ gcc -DPROTECT_ME=1 1.c && ./a.out
a[0]=0
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=3
a[4]=4
a[5]=5
The process had written to a bad place
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: That's a really good idea. but unfortunately I can't use dynamic allocation. I have to protect the stack, or at least what's right after a buffer in the stack.